# Bash identify files with all permissions

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a simple bash script which should copy all files with complete permissions from some folders sent as parameters to a new folder.

This is what I have so far:

```
for dir in $@
do
find $dir -perm -exec cp{} newLocation \;
done
```

It says that -exec is not a known command here. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to find files with complete permissions (please clarify) or do you want to copy files keeping all (i.e. complete) permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-perm requires a parameter that is permissions. What is happening here is that find is trying to interpret -exec as that permission.

You probably want something along the lines of

```
find $dir -perm 777 -exec cp {} newLocation \;
```

Comment: thank you! in this case it seems that the copy function is wrong because i get this following error `No such file or directory`. Sotry.. i'm a complete noob here..

Comment: You can always try and remove the -exec part to see what files you will find. If there are spaces in those, then cp would get confused

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use something different than find

try rsync:

```
rsync -av $dir newlocation/$dir
```

or tar:

```
cd $dir; tar cf - . | (cd newlocation; tar xvf -)
```

it could be done just with find of course, but why reinvent the wheel ?